# C++ accessing variable from other function

Tags: c++

I'm trying make number guessing game with qt creator. I need to access a variable from another function. I was able to do that on python by adding "self." to beggining of variable but I can't do it on C++. Here's a sample what I am trying to do:

```
void function1()
{
   int i;
}

void function2()
{
   I need to access i here.
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use. Parameters.

Comment: Did you learn how to pass things to and return things from functions?

Comment: Make `i` global by declaring it outside of both functions.

Comment: I would suggest reading a tutorial on the mechanics of scope. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Comment: @KhouriGiordano:  The cases where using a global are the most correct architectural choice are few and far between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pointers, classes or global variable ( I'd recommend pointers or a class tho)

```
void f1(int *iPtr)
{
    cout << "value= " <<*iPtr << endl;
}

void f2(int *iPtr)
{
   *iPtr = *iPtr + 5; // access ( modify ) variable here
    cout << "after addition = " << *iPtr << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int *iPtr;
    iPtr = &i; // point pointer to location of i
    f1(iPtr);
    f2(iPtr);
// after f1() value of i == 5, after f2() value of i == 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the equivalent behavior in C++ would be a member variable.

If you're not already, I'd suggest using a class. So, in your header file define it something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    void function1();
    void function2();

  private:
    int i;
};
```

If you're not using C++ classes, then you can define "i" in the header file but that will make it global - in essense. And, probably not the best practice.

Comment: Just because you *can* use classes in C++ doesn't mean you *have to*.  But I won't downvote.

Comment: But i need to make i resetted every time button(function1) clicked in order to get new random numbers. That's why I need to declare it in function1. Also thanks I'll check passing and returning variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access a variable from another function since they exist only on the stack and they are destroyed when the function exits. Use a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare i as a global variable and just assign it the random number once you have chosen it. That way you could still generate a random number and use it in another function.

```
int i;
void function1()
{
   int randNum;
    // get random number here
   i = randNum;
}

void function2()
{
   // do stuff with i here
}
```